# Intuitive (?) inequality extremal inequality

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, measure-concentration

Consider $N$ pairs of random variables $(X_i, Y_i)$. $X_i$ are iid, with $EX_i=0$ and $EX_i^2=1$. The same conditions hold for $Y_i$. Moreover all $X_i$ are independent of all $Y_j$. It seems very reasonable that $\sup_i|X_i+Y_i| > \sup_i|X_i|$ with high probability:

$$P\left(\sup_i |X_i| \le \sup_i |X_i+Y_i| +\epsilon \right) < \exp(-c\epsilon^2)$$ 
But is it true? I can't find counterexamples and yet don't know how to attack the problem.

Comment: maybe, another sign of the main inequality?

Comment: in any case, $N$ must appear somehow in the inequality

Comment: Yes, I agree. I believe the RHS could be an even stronger $\exp(-cN\epsilon^2)$, but would be happy with the original conjecture.

Comment: I guess $c$ here is allowed to depend on the distribution of the $X_i$ somehow?  (If not, what's preventing the $X_i$ from, say, each being $0$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{N^2}$).

Comment: how can you exclude with _exponentially_ small probability that $Y_i\approx -X_i$? I would expect a power law in $\epsilon^2$, not an exponential.

Comment: Carlo, it makes sense but can you think of a counterexample?

Comment: Do you have the first inequality sign in the display equation backwards?